# Question on proof of uniform convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I’m reading the following proof in Childress’ book *Class field theory* and there are two simple analysis steps I don’t see immediately, and are highlighted in green:

1) why does $Arg(s) \leq \theta$ turn into $|s|/Re(s)\leq M$

2) the first equality involving $|e^{-cs}-e^{-ds} |= |s|\int \cdots$

She doesn’t say it, but I’m pretty sure $c$ and $d$ are real (and will be chosen so that $e^c=n$ and $e^d=n+1$

EDIT: I think I figured out answer to part 1. The region $|Arg(s)|\leq \theta$ for $\theta < \pi/2$ is a sector centered at the origin and in the first and fourth quadrant, and so what we want to bound is the absolute value of the slope of the line from $0$ to $s$: if s=x+iy, then the slope is $y/x$, and bounding $y/x$ is equivalent to bounding $1 + \frac{y^2}{x^2} $ and this is equivalent to bounding $\frac{|s|}{Re(s)}$

EDIT: For part 2, I convinced myself of $\leq$ instead of $=$, and that’s only what we need: let’s assume $c<d$ (since that’s what we’ll need anyways) and let $f(t)=e^{-ts}$ and we have 
$$f(d)-f(c)=\int_c^d f’(t) dt = \int_c^d se^{-ts}$$
Then taking absolute values gives
$$|f(c)-f(d)| \leq \int_c^d |s| |e^{-ts}| dt = |s|\int_c^d e^{-tRe(s)} dt$$ 
Where in the last equality I used $|e^s|=|e^{x+iy}| = |e^x||e^{iy}|=e^{Re(s)}$

[image]